# Customize iViewUI <Tag> component

Tags: vue.js, iview

I'm using [iViewUI](https://www.iviewui.com) for my Tag component, but I wanted to customize its size and where the "X" close button is.

I was able to change the width by simply adding a class to the Tag, but for some reason, even i'm trying to override also its children icon, is not responding to the change at all, is not applying it. Checked on browser, not adding it there either.

This is what I've done so far:

```
<Tag class="Badge-tag" color="warning" closable @on-close="removeTag">{{ badge }}</Tag>
```

Then on the less file I added the following:

```
.Badge-tag {
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;

    .ivu-icon.ivu-icon-ios-close {
        position: absolute;
        right: 2px;
        top: 4px;
    }
}
```

I had no luck at all. I don't know why is not setting it.

Comment: Do you use scoped css?

Comment: This CSS is scoped because it's only used in this template. But i attempted adding it inside a non-scoped tag, and it doesn't apply it either.

Comment: @ittus weird thing is, i can target `.ivu-tag` and modify it, but i can't target any of its children through CSS/LESS.

Comment: Are you using `css` or `scss`?

Comment: @ittus im using less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put above css as global css, I think it should work.

I create a demo on [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/haxg597w/1/), please check

If you use scoped css, you can try using [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

```
.Badge-tag {
    width: 60px;
    position: relative;

    /deep/ .ivu-icon.ivu-icon-ios-close {
        position: absolute;
        right: 2px;
        top: 4px;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow!!!! you're a beast. I will test it as soon as possible! Thank you very much! i attempted posting a Feature Request on iViewUI but they closed it with a comment like: "Not gonna happen".. kinda rude. Thanks man!

Comment: Holy smokessss this totally works! i didn't even know there was a /deep/ property O_O but it worked! Thank you soo much man